Webcomic where the main character crashes on a planet and communicates with someone on Earth from the past
It's been a couple years but from what I can remember the main character crashes on a planet and tries to call for help with her radio but the radio picks up a signal from some guy from the past on Earth. She befriends him while she works on her ship to get off the planet and they get into a fight but reconcile after. I think she ends up building a video phone later on before she gets off the planet. It's a pretty short comic but it was pretty good.

Hues of Solitude (episodes 1–34)? The fight is in episode 25. Eden realizes she is in the future (relative to Sage) in episode 32. The video call is episode 33.
